# Kmeans clustering of data in PCA space with Matlab

Tags: matlab, k-means, pca

Processing some data using principle component analysis. We can visualise the output using the biplot function, which if I understand correctly is showing me how my data looks in the PCA space. I want to run some kmeans clustering on the data in the PCA space, but I can't quite get it to work.

```
X = rand(1000, 3);
norm_data = normalize(X);

    %Do the PCA
[coeff,score,latent,~,explained] = pca(norm_data);

figure()
biplot(coeff(:,1:3),'scores',score(:,1:3),'varlabels',{'x','y','z'});
title('Data in PCA space and original axis')
```

I can't quite see how to change "score" in to "clustered score" and plot that with biplot.I've done this but I loose the original axis

```
clustered_score = score(:,1:3);

%do the kmeans on PCA outputs
[idx,C,sumd,D] = kmeans(clustered_score,3);

%three cluster graphs
figure();
scatter3(clustered_score(:,1), clustered_score(:,2), clustered_score(:,3), 15, idx, 'filled');
hold on 
scatter3(C(:,1),C(:,2),C(:,3),'x')
```